# MongoDB, select all entries where inner data-count is greater then zero

Tags: mongodb

I have something like this one.

```
{
    "title" : "",
    "source" : {
        "object" : "some",
        "group" : "some
        "data" : []
    }
}
```

"source.data" or "source" can be undefined at all.

So now I need to select all objects that has count(xxx.source.data) > 0 . How can I do this query? I search for count() and xxx.length (method\property) but still can't understand how to use them in my case.

Added:

```
.find({"source.data": {$exists: true, $size: {$gt: 1}}})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it as follows :

```
db.myObject.find({$and:[{"source.data":{$exists:true}},{"source.data":{$not:{$size:0}}}]})
```

From the mongoDB documentation, it says [$size](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/size/) operator does not accept range queries.

> $size does not accept ranges of values. To select documents based on
>   fields with different numbers of elements, create a counter field that
>   you increment when you add elements to a field.

For greater queries, you can use list index. You can use the following query to find the documents that has data size > 10.

```
db.myObject.find({$and:[{"source.data":{$exists:true}},{"source.data.10" : {$exists:true}}]})
```

Comment: It doesn't work if "source" or "source.data" not defined. (PS: Edited top message.)

Comment: I tried this one. (added to top) So it check existence but not selecting 'size is greater then', where can be trouble?

Comment: I have updated query. Try this one. It checks existence & size of the data array.

Comment: Yes it works, but can you describe how to set 'greater then' ? For example want to select all where count > 10 ...