# How to find a document with array size within a range in MongoDB?

Tags: arrays, mongodb

Given the following document structure:

```
{
  _id : Mongo ID,
  data : [someData1, someData2, ..., someDataN]
}
```

I want to get all documents which `data` size is between `a` and `b` (strict positive integers, consider `a < b` is always true).
I first thought about using [`$size`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/size/#op._S_size), but the Mongo doc states:

> `$size` does not accept ranges of values. To select documents based on fields with different numbers of elements, create a **counter field** that you increment when you add elements to a field.

*(Emphasis mine)*

How to retrieve all the documents with a `data` array of length between `a` and `b` without using a counter?

---

Related but did not solve:

- This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10870354/query-returning-count-of-items-in-mongodb-embedded-collection/10874002#10874002) which suggests using a counter
- This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6722850/querying-internal-array-size-in-mongodb) which asks how to query an internal length
  and got many answers
- This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19221784/mongodb-select-all-entries-where-inner-data-count-is-greater-then-zero/19222054#19222054) which suggests to use: `{ 'data.' + b : { $exists : true } }` but I don't know how reliable it is and how it could apply to a range
- This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7811163/in-mongodb-how-do-i-find-documents-where-array-size-is-greater-than-1) about how to find documents with a minimal array length

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `$exists` operator approach by including multiple terms in your query and building it up programmatically:

```js
var startKey = 'data.' + (a-1);
var endKey = 'data.' + b;
var query = {};
query[startKey] = {$exists: true};
query[endKey] = {$exists: false};
db.test.find(query);
```

So for `a=1` and `b=3`, for example, you end up with a `query` object that looks like:

```js
{
    "data.0" : {
        "$exists" : true
    },
    "data.3" : {
        "$exists" : false
    }
}
```

The first part ensures there are at least `a` elements, and the second part ensures there are no more than `b` elements.

Comment: I was afraid that, when doing something stupid such as `data = []; data[0] = {}; data[10] = {};` (you never know) the final variable `data` could make us end up with different results between doing `'data.n' : { $exists : ...` and a `$size`. After some tests, it occurred that the empty elements are filled by `null` values, so I can confirm the rightness of your answer and also, its awesomeness. Thanks for the clean solution!